# New Table Generation Issue Greendao Android

Tags: android, database, sqlite, greendao

Earlier I am using greendao with 5 tables with library 'org.greenrobot:greendao:3.2.0' now due to some changes i am using 7 tables so if i install fresh app these two new tables are generated and working properly if i upgrade older apk then it generates this Error:

E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such table:

Answer (score 0):

I think you should increase your greendao schema version

**schemaVersion**

> The current version of the database schema. This is used by the *OpenHelpers classes to migrate between schema versions. If you change your entity/database schema, this value has to be increased. Defaults to 1

To do that, add this lines in your build.gradle of your app project:

```
android {
...
}

greendao {
    schemaVersion 2   //incremented schema version to 2 (1 is the default version)
}
```

Comment: but if i increase schema greendao drops all previous tables data